# Set port in requests

Tags: python, networking, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm attempting to make use of `cgminer`'s API using Python. I'm particularly interested in utilizing the `requests` library.

I understand how to do basic things in `requests`, but `cgminer` wants to be a little more specific. I'd like to shrink

```
import socket
import json

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('localhost', 4028))

sock.send(json.dumps({'command': 'summary'}))
```

using `requests` instead.

How does one specify the port using that library, and how does one send such a json request and await a response to be stored in a variable?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. That's why I post as a comment: [Request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is an HTTP library. You can specify the port in the URL `http://example.com:4028/...`. From what I can read in a hurry [here](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer/blob/master/API-README) `cgminer` provides a RPC API. But does it provide an HTTP interface?

Comment: I've re-posted as an answer as you seems to confirm what I've supposed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is an HTTP library.

You can specify the port in the URL http://example.com:4028/....

But, from what I can read in a hurry [here](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer/blob/master/API-README) `cgminer` provides a [RPC](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) API (or [JSON RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC)?) *not* an [HTTP](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)  interface.

Answer (score 27):

As someone who has learned some of the common pitfalls of python networking the hard way, I'm adding this answer to emphasize an important-but-easy-to-mess-up point about the **1st arg of `requests.get()`**:

`localhost` is an alias which your computer resolves to `127.0.0.1`, the IP address of its own loopback adapter. `foo.com` is also an alias, just one that gets resolved further away from the host.

```
requests.get('foo.com:4028')                #<--fails
requests.get('http://foo.com:4028')         #<--works usually
```

& for loopbacks:

```
requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:4028')       #<--works
requests.get('http://localhost:4028')       #<--works
```

this one requires `import socket` & gives you the local ip of your host (aka, your address within your own LAN); it goes a little farther out from the host than just calling `localhost`, but not all the way out to the open-internet:

```
requests.get('http://{}:4028'.format(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())))  #<--works
```

Comment: `172.0.0.1` is incorrect for `localhost`. It's `127.0.0.1`. Typo, or is that why it's failing?

Comment: That was indeed why it was failing.

Comment: what is the triple slash all about? where is the in the docs? `///` i tried googling but no find anything

Comment: Oh whoah interesting. That is a typo & this fails (at least as of 3.6) in python, but some browsers (tested on Firefox) appear to correct this. Technically `http:///<anything>` [wouldn't be a valid URI,](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.2) so theoretically whatever URI parsing...thing/system you hit first should get mad at you or attempt to correct the malformed request. 

Anyhow: `nslookup` returns "`<nameserver> cannot find https:///google.com`", python throws an error, and Firefox corrects the URL for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the port for the request with a colon just as you would in a browser, such as
`r = requests.get('http://localhost:4028')`. This will block until a response is received, or until the request times out, so you don't need to worry about awaiting a response.

You can send JSON data as a POST request using the [`requests.post` method with the `data` parameter](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), such as

```
import json, requests
payload = {'command': 'summary'}
r = requests.post('http://localhost:4028', data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Accessing the response is then possible with `r.text` or `r.json()`.

Note that requests is an HTTP library - if it's not HTTP that you want then I don't believe it's possible to use requests.